# Editing a KML File

Tags: kml, editing

I want to delete ALL popups on a (segmented) line in my KML file. I have opened the file in Open Office and need to do a "Find and Replace" for these instances.

Would it be deleting all  and ?

And if so, what would be my "Find and Replace" search criteria?

I've found this online, [\s\S]*?</description>, but it did not find any instances of that.

I have over 100 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Libreoffice, the healthy successor to OpenOffice.org and I noticed that it doesn't support multiline regular expression matching. So if your description is in several lines in nicely formated KML, that regex would only match the ending tag itself.

But yours didn't match anything, so double check that you have the regular expression option ticked in the find&replace options (below the input fields).

Perhaps it would work to just delete the ending or starting tags, but it looks like you'll need a different tool for a proper solution (perl and similar come to mind).

Answer (score 0):

Holy smokes!

That worked.

All I did was find/replace the unwanted tags to something that would likely not be a recognized tag, Google Earth ignored those foreign tags, and it worked!

Thank you Community.